# Is there a jQuery plugin to select user emails into a text field? Like Facebook

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, extjs

I am looking for something similar to Facebook massage "To" field.

ExtJS has very nice UI component called Ext.ux.BoxSelect. Is there anything similar for jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/ ([demo](http://loopj.com/tokeninput/demo.html))